# Gain (remote) control of Samsung Galaxy S3 with broken display

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3, remote-control, broken-screen

I have physically broken my SGS3's (i9300) display, and thought the phone was now just trash. But as I came home with it in my pocket, to my surprise, it connected to my Wifi, synced my files with my desktop, connected to WhatsApp web, and even rang when someone called. In short, it seems to be in working order other than the display not working at all (not accepting any touch inputs either).

Now, replacing the display is not economically feasible, but it would be nice if I could use the working phone for something - I was thinking microserver, IP camera, Wifi repeater, there are all kinds of things I could think of.

If only I could find a way to remotely control it.

Here is what I have, exactly:

- Samsung Galaxy SIII i9300
- Running CyanogenMod version 11
- TWRP probably around version 2.7
- Root is enabled
- USB debugging is enabled (but not root via USB)
- 3rd party apps are enabled
- Tasker is installed and running

I also have an SD card I could put in the phone and a working USB cable connecting it to my PC.

Can anyone think of a way to McGuyver together a way for me to gain control over the phone ?

Comment: You can try the solution  [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/remote-control?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and then tell us using an answer or an [edit] what worked or did not work for you. Your device supports OTG so you can use a mouse with an OTG cable for installation and setup of particular apps, if they are required.

Comment: It seems you linked to a search, not any particular post. I have no OTG cable around, but I'll try to pick one up when I head to the city later today. In the meantime I have updated my post; I managed to enable ADB access (I found the RSA keyfiles from an older, authorized Windows install). Unfortunately, root via USB is disabled, but this still seems like a huge step forward.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation and solved it: I got another i9300 and used the touchscreen of the good one to install whatever needed -  I rooted the broken phone, installed kodi to use it as a media player and connected the phone to my TV screen via hdmi. I also installed a ssh server and now have everything my raspberry pi has but have a more powerful device. Th second i9300 is not needed any more and will be given to my cousin :-)